# OnTouchListener, ACTION_UP fires automatically after 30 second timeout

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I need the user to be able to touch and hold a button/imageview for a long time (> 30 seconds).
unfortunately after ~30 seconds an ACTION_UP is fired automatically.
Do you have any idea how i can prevent or bypass this event and keep tracking the users touch?

This is essential for the control of my app.

Comment: Is your screen going to sleep? You may have to implement a wakelock or prevent the screen from going off.

Comment: no screen is on all the time it's not a sleep issue.

Comment: i found out that i only experience this behaviour on my motorola milestone phone. in the emulator this "timeout" does not occure.

Comment: @Goddchen, I have noticed the same behavior on some phones. the timeout occurs at varying lengths depending on the phone it seems. I have tested with a Motorola Atrix, Motorola Droid 2 Global as well as an HTC 4G. The ACTION_UP event fires up after some time. Did you ever find a solution to this ?

Comment: The same happens on Motorola XT720. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: it seems to be some kind of "prevent-ghost-click-events" feature of the actual touchscreen driver. After some timeout it fires the ACTION_UP event on it's own for any "ghost" click events...

Comment: Did you find any work-around?  This is happening on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 and after the ACTION_UP incorrectly fires after 20 seconds, there is no further event when the user really does lift their finger from the screen.  And there's nothing in Logcat that could be used to detect this either...

Answer (score 1):

It happens on my motorola me525 also,only last 20 seconds.
I advise you use a layout(for example linearlayout)instead of button or imagebutton
layout can be pressed for a long time as you want

Answer (score 1):

At least for Motorola Xoom, as posted in [Motorola Forum](http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/Android-App-Development-for/Spurious-ACTION-UP-Event-on-Motorola-Xoom-PLEASE-FIX/td-p/17683) , Engineering team seems to consider this problem a feature.

There is a possible solution there(for Xoom), don´t know if works.