# Android ACTION_DOWN event automatically executes ACTION_UP event after few seconds

Tags: android, events

I have created an application in which user have to touch an image for near about 10 sec.
So I have registered ACTION_DOWN event. But this event automatically executes ACTION_UP event after few seconds even if user does not take the finger up. Is there any workaround for this problem?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: well most probably your action_down changes to longClick when pressed for a long time, and since your long click isnt being listened, no actions are performed and action_up is executed...try implementing the longClick listener...might help.

Comment: I think what you're seeing is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168687/ontouchlistener-action-up-fires-automatically-after-30-second-timeout but unfortunately there's no workaround...

Answer (score 1):

I'm a java/android noob but here's a code that works for me:

```
class HelloOnTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
        handleTouchEvent(e);
        return true;
    }
}

public void handleTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    int eAct = e.getAction(); 
    if (eAct == 0) Log.d("touch", "press");
    else if (eAct == 1) Log.d("touch", "release");
}
```

And here's a code that doesn't (UP fires twice, first right after DOWN and then when you actually release):

```
public void handleTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    int eAct = e.getAction();
    switch (eAct) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: Log.d("touch", "press");
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: Log.d("touch", "release");
    }
}
```