# Android ACTION_UP triggers automatically within 20 seconds after ACTION_DOWN on a Button

Tags: android, touch, action

I have an `ImageButton`, touch and holding this Button will do voice recording until user lifts his finger up. But after about 20 seconds since the ACTION_DOWN, the ACTION_UP event triggers automatically and I don't know how to avoid this from happening (because I need at Least 60 secs' recording for my app).

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390058/android-action-down-event-automatically-executes-action-up-event-after-few-secon) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168687/ontouchlistener-action-up-fires-automatically-after-30-second-timeout), they're all talking about same issue as mine,but didn't get a perfect answer.

If anyone know why this happening, I'll be very much grateful.

Comment: This could well be a limitation of a capacitative touch screen. After some time, it would reach saturation and no longer be able to determine whether it's actually touched. Write a little test-app that records the time until ACTION_UP and try it on different devices (and with different users). See if there's a trend.

Comment: Then I will not have to care about this, since it's the problem of hardware(which I've never thought it would be). Thank you for making this  clear to me !