# Android Bug(?): onKey after while states it's KeyEvent.ACTION_UP

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OnTouchListener, ACTION_UP fires automatically after 30 second timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168687/ontouchlistener-action-up-fires-automatically-after-30-second-timeout)

I use the following code to check if a key is clicked:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        // Little method to allow the sound to be changed 
        if(keyCode == 24 || keyCode == 25) {
            return false;
        }

        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            //  if(resetKeyPress != true) {
            this.keyCode = keyCode;
            //  resetKeyPress = true;
            if(this.logGameEngineInputLog == true) {
                gameEngineLog.d(classTAG, "Pressed down " + this.keyCode);
            }
            //  }
        }
        else if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP){
            //waitUntilReleased = false;
            //this.changeKeyCode(null);
            if(this.logGameEngineInputLog == true) {
                gameEngineLog.d(classTAG, "Released key " + this.keyCode);

            }

            this.keyCode = null;

            //  resetKeyPress = false;

        }

        return true;
    }
```

When I click a button for a long time, it keeps on saying a button is pressed, however after a while it says the key has been released, even though I'm still holding down the key. Why is it doing this? Is there a way to prevent this? Is this being done on purpose by the Android OS, if so, why?

Comment: Might be similar, however I use the OnKeyListener.

Comment: Is this for a motorola device? If you follow the link on the duplicate question they seem to consider this a 'feature'. Doesn't sound like there is any workaround.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what is the type which handle this event  : View, Activity ?

In the View case, onKey handles hardware key events only (according to the documentation : [Android Reference - View.KeyEventListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html#onKey%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29))

Moreover, if you take a look to this thread : [How to differentiate between long key press and regular key press?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226771/how-to-differentiate-between-long-key-press-and-regular-key-press), you can see an implementation of the Activity.onKeyLongPress() method, and the errors you should not make.